# $L^p$-space convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $({f_n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ such that $\lim
_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_{n}(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere with respect to Lebesgue measure and 
$$\sup_{n\geq 1}||f_n||_{L^4}<\infty.$$

Prove that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}||f_n - f||_{L^3} = 0.$$

Since we're on a finite measure space I see how we get that $f_n \in L^3$.  But I don't see how I can use a convergence theorem on $L^p$ larger than one.

Comment: My approach is to note that $F_n=|f_n-f|\leq2^p(||f_n||^p+||f||^p)=g_n$ so $F_n \rightarrow 0$ and $g_n \rightarrow g = 2^p||f||$ which is integrable.  Thus($F_n\leq g_n$) by the Dominated Convergence Theorem we're finished.  But this assumes that $||f_n||_p \rightarrow ||f||_p$.

Comment: that should be $F_n=|f_n-f|^p....$

Answer (score 3):

A sequence bounded in $L_p$, $p>1$, is uniformly integrable. Using this fact with $p=4/3$, it follows that $(f_n^3)$ is uniformly integrable. It now follows from [Vitali's Convergence Theorem](http://planetmath.org/VitaliConvergenceTheorem.html) that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the $L_3$-norm.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that the sequence is uniformly integrable and arrive at your conclusion.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: The link you sent me is blank.

Comment: Try this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability

Comment: Yea I found that page but its quite unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Fatou's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma),
$$
\|f\|_{L^4}\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_{L^4}\tag{1}
$$

Since $f_n$ converges pointwise, for any $\epsilon>0$ [Egorov's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem) states that except on $E_{\large\epsilon}$, a set of measure $\epsilon$, $f_n\to f$ uniformly. Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\large E_{\Large\epsilon}^c}\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|^3\,\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{2}
$$
Furthermore, by [Hölder's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) with $p=4/3$ and $q=4$, we have
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_{\large E_{\Large\epsilon}}\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|^3\,\mathrm{d}x\le\epsilon^{1/4}\sup_n\|f_n-f\|_{L^4}^3\tag{3}
$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|^3\,\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{4}
$$

Comment: The fact that $f \in L^4$ is also immediate from Fatou's lemma.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Duh! I looked at Fatou and completely missed that since $f$ was the limit, it was also the $\liminf$. Thanks.