# Sequence with bounded l2 norm

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f_i \colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions which converge to $f_\infty$ pointwise. 
How can I prove that $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \int f_i d\lambda=
\int f_\infty d\lambda$, when $||f_i||_2\leq 1$?

My attemp is to use Egorov and then try to use the bound on the $l_2$-norm
in the set with small measure, but I don't know how to prove that $||f_\infty||_2$
is not infinite.

Comment: Do you know Vitali's Convergence Theorem?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183032/lp-space-convergence), also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $||f_n||_2\le1$, $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere, $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]\setminus E$, and $m(E)<\epsilon$. Cauchy-Schwarz shows that $\int_E|f_n|\le\epsilon^{1/2}$. And then Fatou's Lemma shows that $\int_E|f|\le\epsilon^{1/2}$.