# Dose the pointwise limit equal to the $L^{p}$ limit?

Tags: real-analysis

> For $1<p<\infty$ Let $L^{p}=L^{p}[0,1]$ and f be a measurable function on [0,1].If $\left\{f_{n}\right\}\in L^{p}$  where $\left\{\|f_{n}\|_{L^{p}}\right\} $ is bounded and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }f_{n}\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)$ for a.e. $x\in [0,1]$. then prove that$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^{1}_{0}\left|f_{n}\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)\right|dx=0$$

My thought was to use the boundedness of  $\left\{\|f_{n}\|_{L^{p}}\right\} $ to get that $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\leq 2M$,then we can use the dominated convergence theorem to derive the desired result,but I don't know how to obtain that inequality from the boundedness we've already known.

Comment: The boundedness of the $p$-norms implies $(f_n)$ is uniformly integrable. You can use Vitali.

Comment: I don't think you can get the inequality you want (consider $f_n=n^{1/p}\chi_{[0,1/n]}$). But, you could argue as I suggest above, or use an argument similar to robjohn's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183032/lp-space-convergence).

Comment: I think your approach works very well. But I have difficult to prove that $\left\{f_{n}\right\}$ which is $L^{p}$ bounded implies that it's uniformly  integrable. Can you give me some hint? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apply Holder to $\int_E |f| =\int \chi_E\cdot |f|$.

Comment: This result is an almost direct consequence of Vitali Convergence Theorem.  
See, for instance: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem